# def function with a loop

Tags: python, function, loops

I have a question here. I'm trying to get a define function

```
guestlist = ['abc', 'def', 'ghj', 'aaa', 'bbb']
sur = 'zz'

def guest(numberguest):
    newguestlist = []
    for i in guestlist:
        newguestlist.append(i+sur)
        #print(newguestlist)
    for j in newguestlist:
        print(j)
guest(5)
```

The expected output is if i input 5 i should get all 5 names + zz. If i input 4, I should get:
'abczz', 'defzz', 'ghjzz', 'aaazz'

Any help is appreciated.

Update: Sorry I just realized numberguest input is not used. Thanks for helping everyone!

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  But if your code never uses `numberguest`, why would you expect changing it to change the result?

Comment: `numberguest` is never used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
guestlist = ['abc', 'def', 'ghj', 'aaa', 'bbb']
sur = 'zz'

def guest(numberguest):
    newguestlist = []
    for i in range(numberguest):
        newguestlist.append(guestlist[i]+sur)
        #print(newguestlist)
    for j in newguestlist:
        print(j)
guest(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

your question is not good i think but if u wanna that result u can use this function :

```
 guestlist = ['abc', 'def', 'ghj', 'aaa', 'bbb']
 sur = 'zz'

 def guest(numberguest):
     newguestlist = []
     for i in range(0,numberguest):
         newguestlist.append(guestlist[i]+sur)
     print(newguestlist)
     for j in newguestlist:
         print(j)
```

guest(4)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using an in range() loop

```
guestlist = ['abc', 'def', 'ghj', 'aaa', 'bbb']
sur = 'zz'

def guest(numberguest):
  for i in range(numberguest):
    print(guestlist[i] + sur)

guest(5)
```